# Programmatically flatten yaml with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, yaml, flatten

Example input (generally, *any* yaml file with *any* content)

```
some:
  nested:
    entry: paris
another:
  nested:
    entry: tel-aviv
```

Desired output:

```
Map(2) {
  '.some.nested.entry' => 'paris',
  '.another.nested.entry' => 'tel-aviv'
}
```

I tried to use recursion, but *failed to define the base case* (the function `atom`):

```js
import { readFileSync } from 'fs'
import { parse, stringify } from 'yaml'
const yamlData = parse(readFileSync('input.yaml').toString())

// An ugly hack to demonstrate what I want to achieve
function atom(yamlData): boolean {
  const stringified = stringify(yamlData)
  const distance = stringified.search('entry')
  const atomicity = distance === 0;
  return stringified.search('entry') < 3 // obviously not the way ...
}

function flatten(yamlData, prefix: string): Map<string, any>
{
  const flattened = new Map<string, any>();
  for (const key in yamlData) {
    if (atom(yamlData[key])) {
      const abskey = prefix + "." + key;
      const value = stringify(yamlData[key]);
      const a = value.split(": ")[0].trim() // <--- ugly ...
      const b = value.split(": ")[1].trim() // <--- ugly ...
      flattened.set(abskey + "." + a, b)
      continue;
    }
    const flattenedTag = flatten(yamlData[key], prefix + "." + key)
    for (const [keyTag, value] of flattenedTag.entries()) {
      flattened.set(keyTag, value)
    }
  }
  return flattened
}

const flattened = flatten(yamlData, "");
console.log(flattened)
```

Comment: If you say *any* YAML with *any* content, you need to handle the following cases: Sequences (do they become `[1]` etc in the path?), tags (e.g. `!!str`, what should happen with those), anchors & aliases (paths may be infinite in case of cycles, e.g. `x: &a { b: *a}`, what should happen there), non-scalar keys (what happens with `[1, 2]: 3`?), dots in the original key (if original has `a.b: c`, should that dot be escaped somehow?), and multiple documents in the YAML file.

Comment: @flyx that sounds scary ! is there any 90:10 solution ? (90 percent of yaml files out there, 10 percent of effort)

Comment: I don't know statistics on what features are commonly use in YAML files, though non-scalar keys and cycles are definitely exotic. But you definitely need to handle sequences. In any case, the proper base case is „the current value is not an object and not an array“, I wouldn't know how to express that in typescript though.

Comment: Do you *only* want `entry` keys.

Comment: @vera I need to flatten the nested structure like described